# insert multiple rows in to data frame based on index position

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, insert, multi-level

I have two multi level index dataframes like those below. I need to merge them together.
specifically, i need to insert the rows within df2 into df1 based on a matched index - at the end of the level. the data below can show you what i mean, and the expected output is there too. it needs to be 'programmatic and to run for loads of these instances! many thanks in advance

**data**

```
array1 = [["bar", "bar", "baz", "baz", "foo", "foo", "qux", "qux"]]
tupples1 = list(zip(*array1))
index1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tupples1, names=["first"])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8), index=index1)#
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)


array2 = [["bar", "bar","bar","qux","qux","qux","qux"]]
tupples2 = list(zip(*array2))
index2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tupples2, names=["first"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(7), index=index2)
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

**expected output** would be this shape (but with the actual values)

```
array3 = [["bar", "bar","bar", "bar","bar", "baz", "baz", "foo", "foo", "qux", "qux","qux","qux","qux","qux","qux"]]
tupples3 = list(zip(*array3))
index3 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tupples3, names=["first"])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(16), index=index3)
df3.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: with your example, you end up with duplicated index (e.g. `(bar,one)`), is it the same in the real data?

Comment: hi @Ben.T thanks for your comment! yes i do expect the duplicate (in fact what should actually happen is that the bar,one from df2 should totally replace the original bar, one in df2 - but for sanity checking I was going to remove it after inserting the new rows, but perhaps that is not as efficient.)

Comment: Yeah I believe your idea makes it more complicated. How I understand, using `update` after ensuring that df1 has been `reindex` with the `index.union` between df1 and df2 should do what you want. Does the index order matter?

Comment: thanks for the guidance. index order does matter yeah it has to be the same in df1 as in df2

Comment: @Ben.T sorry would you mind telling me exactly what you mean with that? I am trying to follow but I cannot get around a 'ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis' issue when reindex/updating. following that there appears to be no union attribute

Comment: so you can try `df3 = df1.reindex(df1.index.union(df2.index))` and then `df3.update(df2)` (no need of assignation with update). then df3 should have all what you want from df1 and df2. that said it does not keep the index order (see two and three are not good), df3 is sorted by alphabetical order because of the union index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `pd.factorize` on the first index level to get kind of order for this level, once you `concat` both dataframes.

```
np.random.seed(1)
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])

df3 = (
    df3.set_index( # add two index level for sorting
         [list(range(len(df3))), # to have current order of rows
          pd.factorize(df3.index.get_level_values('first'))[0]], # to have order of first index 
         append=True) # to not replace original index
       .sort_index(level=[-1, -2]) # sort as wanted
       .droplevel([-2,-1]) # delete the extra index
)
print(df3)
                     0
first second          
bar   one     1.624345
      two    -0.611756
      one     0.319039
      two    -0.249370
      three   1.462108
baz   one    -0.528172
      two    -1.072969
foo   one     0.865408
      two    -2.301539
qux   one     1.744812
      two    -0.761207
      one    -2.060141
      two    -0.322417
      three  -0.384054
      four    1.133769
```

Note that you could do the same adding the two levels for sorting as columns and use `sort_values`.